# Why does regex with “|” (or/alternation) match differently when order is switched?

Tags: python, regex

I want to clarify a doubt in python - regular expression

```
import re
stri="Item3. Super Market ListsItem4"
#1st print
print(re.sub(r'(Item[0-9]|Item[0-9]\.)', "", stri,))
#2nd print
print(re.sub(r'(Item[0-9]\.|Item[0-9])', "", stri,))
```

In the stri, I need to remove the "Item4" and "Item3."

output -

```
'. Super Market Lists'

' Super Market Lists'
```

My question is, I used `OR(|)` operator for both patterns.

In the 1st print statement, it did not remove the dot(`.`) in the given string. And in the 2nd print statement, I switched the pattern with `OR` operator. In this time, it removed the dot(`.`) in the string. Why it happens like this

Thank you

Comment: Because the alternatives are processed from left to right.

Comment: Try to ensure titles are meaningful summaries. Also, the problem / test-case can be further reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because it first tries to match the left operand of the OR operator.

Because it matches without the dot, it removes the matched part without looking into the right operand.

Comment: This answer will help, thank you